# How to create virtual server for sql server and redirect requests to a real server in .net

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have an application with 4 services and each service working on 3 databases. I'm supposed to test each service on three different servers.

The problem is that I find it too hard to switch connection strings every time for each service and I always forget something, so I thought maybe I can create a virtual server application which redirects any request to the real server as it's hard at this time to refactor these services and make them use common configuration file.

My idea is to set connection strings like this:

```
Data Source=MyVirtualServer;Database=Db;User Id=user;Password=xxx
```

and *MyVirtualServer* is an application developed with .NET and when any SQL request comes to it, it redirects this request to the real server so the final connection string should look like this:

```
Data Source=MyRealServer;Database=Db;User Id=user;Password=xxx
```

The process flow will be like this:

- The service connects to my virtual server application
- The virtual server application redirects the connection to the real server
- The service tries to read data using SELECT statement
- The application redirects the request to the real server and returns the result

I don't know if that is possible or not, so I need your suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think i can do that by writing a custom provider, right ?

Comment: Are you planning on modifying the request or the results at the virtual server layer, or are you just doing it so you can do stuff like load balancing?